# Removing annotations from a Modelica model

Tags: annotations, modelica, dymola, openmodelica, jmodelica

I'm developing a Modelica library and need to produce a document with source code listings. I'd like to be able to include the source of the Modelica models without annotations.

I could manually edit them out, but I'm looking for a more automated strategy. I'm guessing the most convenient and straightforward approach is to use some tool to save `.mo` files with no annotations and include those in my document (I'm using `\lstinputlisting` in LaTeX).

Is it possible to do this? I have access to Dymola, OpenModelica and JModelica. **Dymola** is obviously capable of producing such a listing, as it's able to include it in the automatically generated documentation (File > Export > HTML...). I've been looking into scripting with Dymola and **OpenModelica**, but haven't found a way to do this either.

**JModelica** seems like it could be a good option, but I don't have experience working with Python. If this is possible and someone gives me some pointers, I'm willing to look into it myself. I found a mention to a [`prettyprint`](http://www.jmodelica.org/5254) function that might do the job, but I'm not sure where to start. I can't even find reference to that function in the [latest documentation](http://www.jmodelica.org/api-docs/usersguide/2.0/index.html).

It would also be more convenient for me to find a way of doing it with Dymola/OpenModelica (whether through the UI or by using a script). Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use `saveTotalModel("total.mo", MyModelName)` in OpenModelica. This will strip most annotations (not ones used for code generation if I remember correctly) and pretty-print the source code including all dependencies. Then you just copy-paste the models/packages that you want to include in the listing. Or if you prefer, you can do something like the following to only include code for a particular model:

```
loadModel(Modelica);
loadFile("MyModel.mo");
saveTotalModel("total.mo", MyModel.A.B);
clear();
loadFile(MyModel);
str := list(MyModel.A.B);
writeFile("MyModel.A.B.listing", str);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @sjoelund.se. I'm not sure how to implement your solution. I have [one file per model](https://github.com/raulrpearson/PVSystems). Ideally, I'd like to be able to save a complete version of the library without annotations. Were am I supposed to input these commands? I'm sorry, I'm know about scripts but I'm not familiar with them. I'm trying to input them in a Compiler CLI window I opened in OMEdit. I got this `saveTotalModel("total.mo",PVSystems.Electrical.PVArray) >>
true` but I have no clue where that ended up! (`cd` returns nothing)

Comment: You can use cd() as command to see where it is, or if you are on Windows it should be saved in %TEMP%\OpenModelica\OMEdit

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AdrianPop, indeed `cd()` worked and I found the file in the `%TEMP%` folder. I have been trying to create the results I want and found that I can create an annotation-less version of the model by using `saveTotalModel("ModelWithStuff.mo", PVSystems.Subpkg.Model)`. But that includes some extra stuff that I don't want. I then `clear()`, load _that_ version and extract the part I want with `writeFile("ModelClean.mo", list(PVSystems.Subpkg.Model))`

Comment: I accepted this answer, thanks for taking the time to write it. I do think it can be improved by explaining where one can issue those commands (I used the Compiler CLI, but I'm looking into creating a script, not sure how to do that). I also struggled to understand the commands themselves, why load Modelica, where things were being saved, why the second `loadFile` has a different syntax than the first one, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the [resulting script](https://github.com/raulrpearson/PVSystems/blob/cc9fabdbcf81d0b37661bcf7de4f02f15f4fe478/PVSystems/Resources/Scripts/OpenModelica/PublishListings.mos) inspired by this answer.

Comment: The first command is loadModel (basically loads a library from the directory pointed by the OPENMODELICALIBRARY env variable), the second is loadFile which loads an actual file (it could be a package.mo which will load  a library). Put the command in a file with extension .mos and run it via command line using omc executable. Documentation of API commands is here: https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/OpenModelica.Scripting.html
More information here (on invocation, etc): https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/